# Right procedure for Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation in multi-class classification

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I am intending to implement a existent [method](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/FG.2015.7163092) to recognize sign language. The model uses a data-set of N (375) classes but with only 3 examples per class.

The authors used Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation (LOOCV) to assess the performance.  I assessed each class Ci against to the rest of data samples (after I extracted Ci). Using the results I constructed a confusion matrix, but I perceived that the obtained results (accuracy) are too optimistic (I think I am wrong!).

1. Someone could teach me the correct way to do LOOCV for multi-classes ?
2. It is reasonable to think that LOOCV is suitable to assess models for data-sets with a few samples?
3. Does exist other alternatives to assess models trained with a few examples?